# Multiple select for cities

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one dropdown which consists of list of groups and respective items for the groups.I want to select a group so that automatically the groups items should also select based on the selection of groups in the dropdown.if the group item selected then the whole group should be deselected

Here is my html code :

```
  <option class="options" value="allinone" id="puneid" >Pune</option>
       <option class="options" value="1">pune-loc</option>
    <option class="options" value="2">pune-loc1</option>
    <option class="options" value="3">pune-loc2</option>
    <option class="options" value="16">pune-loc3</option>

    <option class="mumbai" value="allinone" id="mumbaiid" >Mumbai</option>
    <option class="mumbai" value="1">mum-loc</option>
    <option class="mumbai" value="2">mum-loc1</option>
    <option class="mumbai" value="3">mum-loc2</option>
    <option class="mumbai" value="16">mum-loc3</option>
    <option class="mumbai" value="26">mum-loc5</option>
</select>
```

And my js code is :

```
$('#siteSelector').click(function(){
    var self = $(this);
    if(self.val() == 'all'){
       self.children().prop('selected',true).click()

    }
    else
    {
        self.find('.options:first').prop('selected', false)
    }
})
$('#mumbaiid').click(function(){
     var self = $(this);
    if(self.val() == 'allinone'){

       self.children().prop('selected',true).click()

    }
    else
    {
        self.find('.mumbai:first').prop('selected', false)
    }
    })
```

I want an output like when I click on the Pune the locations under pune should select and When I click on the Mumbai ,the location under mumbai should select.

and when we select the both cities then the two cities Mumbai and pune should select.And when we click on the sub localities then only the sub localities should select

Comment: did you tried anything related to it. You can google for multiple selection in dropdownlist. Have a look http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Multiple-Select-MultiSelect-DropDownList-with-CheckBoxes-in-ASPNet-using-jQuery.aspx

Comment: I am working on the html only..I don't know asp.can you please provide the code in html and js

Comment: You can use HTML inputs inplace of asp.net controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#mumbaiid').click(function(){
     var self = $(this);
    if(self.val() == 'allinone'){

       $("."+self.attr('class')).prop('selected',true);
       // or you can also use 
       // self.siblings("."+self.attr('class')).prop('selected',true);

    }
    else
    {
        self.find('.mumbai:first').prop('selected', false)
    }
    })
```

Here is working demo. 
http://jsfiddle.net/ax0bhyy6/

you can get the selected values like this:

```
$("select option:selected").each(function (){
   alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Now it's working...but how can we get all the selected values

Comment: Where do you want to get ? client side or server side??

Comment: client side it self...after that I will post these values to server side in the form php file

Comment: Some times onclcik on id function is not loading...in my system it's working fine..but some times it's not working in my system and others also ...what could be the possible reason for this ?

Comment: I have used a  $( window ).load(function() {});

Comment: After that I put the code what you suggested me @Brijesh Bhatt

Answer (score 0):

**Using this one*

```
<select multiple>
<option class="options" value="allinone" id="puneid" >Pune</option>
<option class="options" value="1">pune-loc</option>
<option class="options" value="2">pune-loc1</option>
<option class="options" value="3">pune-loc2</option>
<option class="options" value="16">pune-loc3</option>

<option class="mumbai" value="allinone" id="mumbaiid" >Mumbai</option>
<option class="mumbai" value="1">mum-loc</option>
<option class="mumbai" value="2">mum-loc1</option>
<option class="mumbai" value="3">mum-loc2</option>
<option class="mumbai" value="16">mum-loc3</option>
<option class="mumbai" value="26">mum-loc5</option>
```